# stop animation when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uibutton

I am having the code below, which is an animation of a UIButton. But when the button is pressed, i want the animation stop at once and do something else, while if the animation continue it does something else. My problem is that even i press the button, the animation continue and it will do both step 1 and 2.

What am i missing in the code?

```
int frame1 = 600;
    int frame2 = 100;
    hit11 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((arc4random() % (frame1 - frame2)+frame2),200,20,20)];
      [hit11 addTarget:self action:@selector(hit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [hit11 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touchrightdown.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:hit11];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        hit11.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(7,7);
        hit11.alpha=0.5;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            //DO STEP 2.
hit11.hidden=YES;

        }



        NSLog(@"got hit");


    }];

-(void) hit:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(@"1/10");
    //DO STEP 1.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
[sender.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

in your hit:(UIButton*)sender method.